# HasMany Eloquent relation in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation

I try to get the number of logged user posts `count` so it shows to logged user for example how many post or comment they published so far:

What I have so far is `author_id` column in `posts` table which will refer to user id

[image: posts table image]

This is my `Post` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{


    public function author() {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

and this is my `User` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'role_id',
        'email',
        'password',
        'name',
        'avatar',
        'remember_token',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'author_id');
    }


}
```

This is my `PostController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\Auth;
use App\User;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);
        $countTodayOrders = Post::whereRaw('Date(created_at) = CURDATE()')->count();

        return view('theme.index',  compact('posts', 'countTodayOrders'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function single($slug) {
        $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
        $countTodayOrders = Post::whereRaw('Date(created_at) = CURDATE()')->count();
        return view('theme.single', compact('post', 'countTodayOrders'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what is my mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: btw what you're getting in `$countTodayOrder` ?

Comment: Posts that published in that day.

Answer (score 0):

Well i figure it out :)

i ignored all model roles and directly used controller inserted data from Database and compare it with user id if it's true (same) will return the number.

here is the code for you if you need it `PostController`:

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);
        $countTodayOrders = Post::whereRaw('Date(created_at) = CURDATE()')->count();
        $postscount = DB::table('posts')
            ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                      ->from('users')
                      ->whereRaw('author_id = id');
            })
            ->get();

        return view('theme.index',  compact('posts', 'countTodayOrders', 'postscount'));
    }
```